# Priority Queue Implementation in STL

Tags: stl, priority-queue

I was looking at a piece of code, where I came across:

```
priority_queue<trainer, vector<trainer>, function<bool(trainer,trainer)> > p(comp);
```

here, trainer is a user-defined struct and comp is a comparator function. I am having trouble understanding what the 3rd argument `function<bool(trainer,trainer)>` mean and why is the comparator function in parantheses.

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue): Isn't the third parameter supposed to contain the comparator and the parantheses is supposed to pass a range of something?

Answer (score 1):

`priority_queue` has three template parameters. A type, a container, and a comparison function.

In your example, the type is `trainer`, the container is `vector<trainer>`, and the type of the comparison object is `function<bool(trainer,trainer)>`.

When you instantiate one of these things, you need to pass it a specific comparison function, and in this case that is `comp`.

If `comp` is just a function pointer, then it will be (implicitly) converted to a `std::function<bool(trainer, trainer)>` object, which will be used by the `priority_queue`